# Web component inside another web component

Tags: javascript, web-component

I wanted to implement a remove-button web component. It goes up the DOM, finds a certain element and removes it with itself. The problem arose when I used this component inside another component. I still could traverse the DOM outside the remove-button component, but only up to the boundaries of the parent component. Is there any way to operate the DOM outside the parent component? This is a createdCallback of my component:

```
proto.createdCallback = function() {
  let custom_element = this;
  let target = custom_element.getAttribute('target');
  let clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
  clone.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function() {
    custom_element.closest(target).remove();
  });
  this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: `custom_element.remove()` not working?

Comment: It is, but that's not what I want. That's why I go up the DOM: custom_element.closest(target).remove(); and then remove the found element which also removes the web component itself because it's lower in the DOM. The problem is that if this remove-button component is inside another web component I can't go up the DOM higher than the parent component.

Comment: you can bind an event higher up, and then raise it on a nested element, where it will bubble up to the handler, passing needed details with it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more, please?

Comment: `outer.addEventListener("something", console.info.bind(console), true);` and `inner.dispatchEvent(new Event("something", {data:[inner, 123, "a string"]}))`

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events for more info...

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just select with query like;

```
removeButton.addEventListener("click",()=>document.querySelector(".removal").remove())
```